# How do I accurately zoom in on a specific point on pinch gesture (with multiple pinches)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, matrix, uigesturerecognizer, transformation

I am trying to zoom a quad in my iOS application. It needs to zoom not based on the center of the quad, but based on the centroid of the pinch.

**I am able to do this correctly - however only for the first pinch gesture. On subsequent pinch gestures, it works, but it drifts a little bit and doesn't quite seem accurate. I am unable to figure out what to do.**

There are a few SO questions around this, and I've been through most, if not all of them. None of them accurately address my problem.

Also note that I'm scaling and translating a quad (which is rendered into a GLKView), and not the view itself. Most solutions I've seen deal with transforming the views directly.

Here's the code for the pinch gesture and handling:
First in viewDidLoad:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self action:@selector(respondToPinchGesture:)];
pinchRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
pinchRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
[glView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
```

Where glView is a GLKView object.
And the handler:

```
- (IBAction)respondToPinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || [recognizer numberOfTouches] < 2) return;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        point = [recognizer locationInView:glView];
        point.x *= glView.contentScaleFactor;
        point.y *= glView.contentScaleFactor;
        point.y = height - point.y;

        anchor = GLKVector3Make(point.x, point.y, 0);
        lastScale = 1.0;
    }

    if (fabs(recognizer.scale - lastScale) > 0.01){

        GLfloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - recognizer.scale);
        lastScale = recognizer.scale;

        new_anchor_point = anchor;
        new_anchor_point = GLKVector3MultiplyScalar(new_anchor_point, scale);
        GLKVector3 translate = GLKVector3Subtract(anchor, new_anchor_point);

        path.transform = GLKMatrix4TranslateWithVector3(path.transform, translate);
        path.transform = GLKMatrix4Scale(path.transform, scale, scale, 0);

        cumulative_translate = GLKVector3Add(cumulative_translate, translate);
    }

}
```

Any pointers appreciated. I am 2 days into this and even a vague suggestion might be helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using:

```
-(GLKVector3)get_touch_point_on_view:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    CGRect bounds = [glView bounds];
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:glView];
    point.y = bounds.size.height - point.y;
    return GLKVector3Make((point.x * glView.contentScaleFactor - total_translation.x)/total_scale,
                                   (point.y * glView.contentScaleFactor - total_translation.y)/total_scale, 0);
}
- (void)respondToPinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        lastScale = 1.0;
    }

    [self get_touch_point_on_view:recognizer];

    if (fabs(recognizer.scale - lastScale) > 0.01){

        GLfloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - recognizer.scale);
        lastScale = recognizer.scale;
        total_scale *= scale;

        path.transform = GLKMatrix4TranslateWithVector3(path.transform, centroid);
        path.transform = GLKMatrix4Scale(path.transform, scale, scale, 0);
        path.transform = GLKMatrix4TranslateWithVector3(path.transform, GLKVector3Negate(centroid));
        total_translation = [self get_total_translation];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to

- remember the previous transformation matrix upon RecognizerStateBegan,
- construct your new transformation matrix for pinch zoom assuming the view or object have not been transformed before.
- Then, concatenate two matrices together. This will be your final matrix for transforming your object or view.

Comment: That is obvious. And I clearly could do the zoom. The problem was the drift on subsequent pinches. You really should read the question in detail.